# dart:cli start nano command and parse than the content

Tags: flutter, dart, command-line-interface, nano

**hallo guys**,

i want to write a `cli dart app`. which starts `nano` .... and at exit save the input should be parsed to a `File(...)` as content.

i already tried to look for something like this on the pub.dev site, but couldn't find anything. maybe i'm looking for it wrong ... ?

for example:

```
var output = *start nano*

var file = File(argResults!['file-name']).writeAsStringSync(output);
```

how can i do that?

Comment: To run another process, you can use [`Process.run`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-io/Process/run.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the 'editor' function in the dcli package.

https://onepub.dev/packages/dcli

It starts an editor and waits for it to close.